# pyqt5のdesignerをWSL環境で起動できるか

Tags: python, ubuntu, wsl, pyqt5

## 概要

秀和システムの[Pythonプログラミングパーフェクトマスター](https://www.shuwasystem.co.jp/book/9784798070667.html)の5章を参考にGUIアプリの作成を試みています。
venvで仮想環境を作り、pyqt5とqt5-toolsを導入したところまではよかったんですが、designerを起動するところでハマりました。正常に起動させる方法を教えてください。

## 状態

```
$ pip list
Package          Version
---------------- ----------
click            8.1.7
pip              24.0
PyQt5            5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5        5.15.2
PyQt5-sip        12.13.0
qt5-applications 5.15.2.2.3
qt5-tools        5.15.2.1.3
```

```
$ qt5-tools designer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/OneDrive/infoTech/py_demo/.venv/bin/qt5-tools", line 5, in <module>
    from qt5_tools.entrypoints import main
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/OneDrive/infoTech/py_demo/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qt5_tools/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    qt_applications = import_it("qt_applications")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Owner/OneDrive/infoTech/py_demo/.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/qt5_tools/__init__.py", line 9, in import_it
    import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

## 環境

- Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, WSL 2.0.9.0
- Python 3.12
- vscode 1.82

## 補足

純粋なwindows環境で試したところ、`qt5-tools designer`では同様のエラーが出ましたが、直接exeファイルを実行すると正常にデザイナが起動しました。ただ、win環境は嫌です。

## 追記

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`でインストール

```
$ qt5-tools designer
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, xcb.
```

で、[DISPLAYなし環境でpyqt5を使おうとするとエラー（`qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.`）の解決策](https://qiita.com/seigot/items/4233b63cf542ae5cf30f)を参考に
`$ export QT_QPA_PLATFORM=offscreen`を実行

```
$ qt5-tools designer
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
This plugin does not support propagateSizeHints()
^C
Aborted!
```

エラーが消えたと思ったら別のエラー

Comment: エラーメッセージに明確に`pkg_resources`がimport出来ないと書かれているので、その名前で検索すれば色々と情報が見つかると思います。[ArchLinuxのPythonでpkg_resourcesモジュールが見つからない](https://lufia.org/notes/2022/0209.html), [Djangoサーバー起動時にModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'が出た件](https://qiita.com/weblabo/items/f700b59fec9bbeff8589), [Does Python setuptools pkg_resources module support everything pip does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76030902/9014308) 今は pkg_resources 自身は非推奨のようですが、setuptools を install することで import error は解消されそうです。

Comment: 今回のエラーと直接関係があるか分かりませんが、Windows 側のディスクを参照しているのが気になります。「venv で仮想環境を作り」はあくまで WSL 内で作ったものなのでしょうか？ / また、OneDrive 配下にファイルを置いているのも余計なトラブルの元になるので避けた方が無難です。

Comment: こんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれませんね。[Qt Designer and Python: Build Your GUI Applications Faster](https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/)

Comment: あるいは古い記事ですがこちらが参考になるかも。[PyQt5をUbuntuで使うときにGUI周りでエラー (WSL2)](https://qiita.com/momomo_rimoto/items/83917d3f9f5dd35457e1)